# Sorting numbers with SI scale factors

Tags: python, numbers

I have a CSV file that contains a column whose values are given with SI scale 
factors. I need to do a numeric sort on that column. Specifically, the CSV file contains a list of famous astronomical objects (the Messier objects) and I need to sort them by distance. The kicker is that the distance is given with numbers that use the SI unix prefixes, so a simple sort won't work.  Is there a simple way of doing this?

Here is a very abbreviated version of the file:

```
"Messier Number","Distance"
"M1","6.5 kly"
"M2","33 kly"
"M7","980 ly"
"M16","7 kly"
"M19","29 kly"
"M31","2.5 Mly"
"M49","56 Mly"
```

Here is what I have so far::

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('m.csv') as f:
    messier = sorted(DictReader(f), key=lambda e: e['Distance'])

for entry in messier:
    print('{Messier Number:>5s} {Distance}'.format(**entry))
```

But this does an alphabetic sort rather than a numeric sort:

```
 M31 2.5 Mly
 M19 29 kly
  M2 33 kly
 M49 56 Mly
  M1 6.5 kly
 M16 7 kly
  M7 980 ly
```

I could try to split up the distance and interpret the k and M myself, but 
that seems like the wrong approach. After all, use of metric prefixes is very 
common. There must be some support for this already.  Any pointers would be 
greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units

Comment: it does support `ly` out of box, but not kly, Mly... pfft.

Comment: Oh, I see you've mixed units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use 
[QuantiPhy](https://quantiphy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It is a nice package 
that reads and writes numbers with SI scale factors and units. QuantiPhy 
privides Quantity, which subclasses float. It converts your string into 
something that behaves like a float, which allows you to do a numeric sort. The 
string may include SI scale factors and units.  The scale factor is properly 
interpreted.  In this case the units are not needed and so would be effectively 
ignored.

Modifying your code to the following should work.

```
from csv import DictReader
from quantiphy import Quantity

with open('m.csv') as f:
    messier = sorted(DictReader(f), key=lambda e: Quantity(e['Distance']))

for entry in messier:
    print('{Messier Number:>5s} {Distance}'.format(**entry))
```

With this code the sort comes out right:

```
  M7 980 ly
  M1 6.5 kly
 M16 7 kly
 M19 29 kly
  M2 33 kly
 M31 2.5 Mly
 M49 56 Mly
```

Comment: Ah that's a nice package.

Comment: Yeah, I really prefer using SI notation rather than e-notation, so I tend to use it quite a bit. I am quite happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an overkill, compared to the other answer in this case, but here's code using the [`units`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units) library

```
from units import unit, predefined, scaled_unit
from csv import DictReader

predefined.define_units()

# units defines `ly` as multiple of metres, but doesn't define
# any of the SI prefixes for these, so we do these units by hand

scaled_unit('kly', 'ly', 1000)
scaled_unit('Mly', 'ly', 1000 * 1000)
scaled_unit('Gly', 'ly', 1000 * 1000 * 1000)


def make_distance(d):
    number, un = d.split()
    return unit(un)(float(number))


with open('m.csv') as f:
    messier = sorted(DictReader(f), key=lambda e: make_distance(e['Distance']))


for entry in messier:
    print('{Messier Number:>5s} {Distance}'.format(**entry))
```

output

```
   M7 980 ly
   M1 6.5 kly
  M16 7 kly
  M19 29 kly
   M2 33 kly
  M31 2.5 Mly
  M49 56 Mly
```